# How do I view a trusted certificate in the Remote Desktop Connection client?

Tags: remote-desktop

When you use the Remote Desktop Connection client to connect to a remote computer that does not have a valid SSL certificate, you are presented with a box similar to this:
[image: RDP certificate error]

I already know how to deal with this, to make the box not appear at every connection ("check Don't ask me again..."). I also know how to make the box reappear after "Don't ask me again" has been checked. (There are several posts to this effect here on superuser.) An option in this dialog allows you to review the server certificate.

My question is when using Remote Desktop Connection client to connect to a server that **has a valid certificate** issued by a trusted certification authority, how do I view the certificate? (Assume that I do not have access to the certificate store on the remote server.)

In the connection bar of Remote Desktop Connection version 6.3.9600 there appears a padlock, similar to what you might see in a web browser. However, clicking on the padlock only reveals [image: MSTSC Padlock dialog]

Again, how do I view the certificate used by Remote Desktop Connection when the certificate is valid?

**EDIT:** In my initial testing, I was using a client PC (non-domain) to connect to the server on the same subnet. The security (padlock) icon in MSTSC indicated authentication by kerberos. A subsequent test from a PC on a remote network indicated authentication by server certificate, and gave me the option to view the certificate.

So now I am wondering why the local connection authenticated by kerberos and the remote connection by certificate?

Comment: P.S. -- Credit for the error message image goes to Ian Boyd ( http://superuser.com/users/8169/ian-boyd )

Comment: Is this a corporate network? e.g. a managed domain

Comment: The server in question is in an Active Directory domain. The client PC is not joined to the domain, and has not imported the certificate. The server has supposedly been configured with an SSL certificate from a third-party certification authority, not the Windows CA in the domain. I need to verify which certificate is actually being used.

Comment: The handshake may be recorded, you could check eventvwr on the client to see what certificate was used.

Comment: I found a workaround for what I needed to do... connect to the server by IP address rather than name. This forces the error message to appear, where I can click to view the certificate. However, it really doesn't answer the question of how to view the certificate when it's valid for the server named in the connection.

Comment: Nice, was it available in eventvwr?

Comment: I did see some things in event viewer, but nothing that really helped. I assume that certs are only cached in memory for the duration of the session, not written to storage.

Comment: Interesting, I thought it would at least list the thumbprint for auditing. Nice find though.

Comment: In my initial tests, I was using a non-domain client PC that was physically on the same subnet as the server. Clicking the padlock icon indicated that authentication was by kerberos. I just did another test from a client PC in a remote network, and the padlock icon indicated that authentication was by server certificate, and gave the option to view the certificate. So now the question: why was it authenticating by kerberos the first time and not by server certificate?

Comment: If the client is on a remote network then the cert is used to sign the connection. Kerberos is local only so it would take precedence in that scenario.

Comment: I don't understand why Kerberos authentication was used if the client and server are not in the same domain.

Comment: Same network/subnet though right? I've read through the wiki and it explains it well, I'd check it out, interesting fallback methods. (Too much for a comment).

Comment: @dkanejs, do you happen to remember what wiki you were referring to here and where we can find it?  I'm facing the same problem as the OP - the Remote Desktop client is telling me "Kerberos" under circumstances where that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Remote Desktop's RDP protocol uses port 3389 and SSL. If you have openssl (or are willing to install it, the swiss army knife for SSL), then you can use this command to capture an RDP server (Terminal Server) certificate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect remoteserver:3389 < nul: |
    openssl x509 -outform PEM > remoteserver.cer
```

That's one line and works on the old command prompt. For PowerShell use:

```
$null | 
    openssl s_client -showcerts -connect remoteserver:3389 |
    openssl x509 -outform PEM > remoteserver.cer
```

This is what's happening

- 'openssl s_client' starts an SSL client.
- nul: or $null is used because we don't have data to send to the server
- '-showcerts' outputs the server certificate (sent by the server)
- '-connect' specifies the host and port

The first invocation of openssl outputs details of the requested ssh connection including the remote server certificate. This output is passed into a second instance of openssl to pull out just the certificate.

- 'openssl x509' starts certificate processing
- '-outform PEM' sets output format to base64 encoding with header and footer.
- '> remoteserver.cer' captures the output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos doesn't use certificates. If the connection was secured with Kerberos then there is no certificate to view on this connection.

Comment: Oddly enough, if there is a valid certificate on the server the client tells you that the connection was secured with both kerberos and a certificate, and allows you to view the certificate.  It seems that it is only if it doesn't like the certificate that it decides to just use Kerberos.